# One-liner to run commands from a file in parallel using xargs

Tags: xargs, parallelism

I have a script like this:

```shell
#!/bin/csh

command 1 \
   -f \"input1\" \
   -l input2 -other_swithes1

command 2 \
   -f \"input1\" \
   -m input2 \
   -l input3 -other_swithes1

command 3 \
   -f \"input1\" \
   -l input2 -other_swithes2
```

so any idea for an one-liner with `xargs` to run these commands in parallel. I tried various variants but all failed. I do not really want to write a script, I think that should have been possible with -d switch and -c, not sure though.

To simplify and extend the problem further, what I have is

```
cat file | grep -v "#.*" | sed -z 's/[\]\n/ /g' | xargs -I {} -n1 -P10 sh -c '{}'
```

and while this does the job there is a particular problem and that is that `\"` get removed. So any clue how to solve that?!

Comment: could probably do something with `xargs -n`, but might need an intermediate scriptlet to put the input arguments in the right places wrt. the options. Also the fact that seem to have one command with three args, and the other two with only two args is an annoyance. Makes the intermediate script more complex.

Comment: But you already have a script. Why don't you just add `&` to the end of each of the three commands in your script? That will run them in parallel.

Comment: @terdon because, when I am running the script, I do not want to run them in parallel, further I can pip prior to xargs and filter out some that I do not run all of them in parallel.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain all this. We need to know the context in order to help you. You're probably looking for GNU `parallel` though, not `xargs`.

Comment: "_I do not really want to write a script_" huh? You've already written one

Comment: It seems like a solution would be to amend your script so you can pass a parameter that allows them to be run in parallel or not as per your whim at run time.

Comment: @roaima (GNU) `xargs` can run things in parallel with `-P` flag, I guess OP is referring to that. But yes, `parallel` is probably the more suitable tool.

Comment: @pLumo my bad, thank you

Comment: @terdon, I did update it and explained my real problem which is that `\"` get lost!

Comment: @roaima that is the output of a tool that I wrote. normal users do not run it in parallel, but since I have enough licenses I would like to run it in parallel because each takes almost a day! So, yes I generate that script but did not write it ;), so let keep it simple and stupid and not talk about changing the file. :D

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel you can do something like:

```
parallel -d '\n\n' < file.csh
```

---

Disclosure: I am the author of this tool.

Answer (score -1):

So the answer is:

```
cat file | grep -v "#.*" | sed -z 's/[\]\n/ /g' | sed -z 's/\"/\\\\"/g' | xargs -I {} -n1 -P10 sh -c '{}'
```

Thanks

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).